# How to find all Nike products with "nikeeeee" keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch db with 15 million products.

I want to write a query to find all Nike products when my user search "nikeeeee" or "nikeoff" or "bestnike" or "nikenike" or "nike-Nike" or some keywords like these.

When I used Fazzy query, The result returned was not relevant.

How can i handle it?

Thanks in advance

To find all Nike products when my user search "nikeeeee"

Comment: Maybe [synonyms](https://www.elastic.co/blog/boosting-the-power-of-elasticsearch-with-synonyms) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @rabbitbr you can use [synonymns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html)

Using synonyms multiple words can point to same token.

Below is working example of it

```
PUT <index-name>
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "synonym"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "synonym"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "lenient": true,
            "synonyms": [
              "nikeeeee,nikeoff,bestnike,nikenike,nike-nike => nike"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
POST <index-name>/_doc
{
  "title":"adidas shoes"
}
```

```
GET <index-name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "bestnike"
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index50",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ky9VF4QBpvliSuG-OTh-",
        "_score" : 0.6931471,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "nike shoes"
        }
      }
    ]
```